# Symfony 5 How to create 2 authentication systems?

Tags: authentication, symfony

I'm working on a Symfony application where i have a classic authentication system for users.
I would like to give the possibility for those users to register a few "team members" where the first user would be the team leader. So in my mind, this could be possible through a second authentication system (this system would have to use the remember me system), and the second category of user : "team members" would be stored in a different table in database.

So the team leader, would be "register" himself the other teammembers, while he's logged in on this own account.

I'm sorry i'm new to Symfony, does anyone know if something like this is even possible ?

Comment: You can do it in many ways, but why not register all the users in the same DB, use a ROLE_TEAM and ROLE_TEAM_LEADER and use a Self-Referencing Mapping (if you use Doctrine) to associate the Team Members. PS: Allow a User to "Register" other users is not a good idea under a security perspective IMO.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for your response. I haven't thought of self-referencing mapping in fact but that's a good idea thank you very much. I agree with you but i must find a solution where the team member just clicks on a link and everything is already setup... also the team leader has to verify his email to validate his account, whereas the team member does not. And Team member must have the always remember me enabled, i did not think i could do that unless creating 2 authenticating systems

Comment: I don't know the details of your project (and which user data you need to create a new user) but You can implement what you want using only one auth system. Also, as it is this is a very broad and opinion based question, so you should start to implement something and come back here with a specific programming problem. If you dive into the Symfony docs you'll find many useful tips to apply on your use case. If you'll face a specific problem open a new question with all details.

Comment: Defiantly need to utilise [Roles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#roles) and have a hierarchy. Keep it with one authentication system and user database. In your admin panel the team leader can have more options available due to their role, like adding users etc.. That's the way i would design it and Symfony's intention.